# VirtualBox Ping strange behaviour

Tags: windows, fedora, virtualbox, ping

I installed 3 guest systems on my virtualbox. Windows 98, Windows XP and Windows Server 2012 R2. Host system is Fedora KDE Plasma.
All VMs are configured with a bridged network adapter and internet works fine.

But pinging works not on every VM or not bidirectional:

Host -> Win98 **works**.
Host -> WinXP **doesn't** work.
Host -> Win2012 **doesn't** work.

Win98 -> Host **works**.
Win98 -> WinXP **doesn't** work.
Win98 -> Win2012 **doesn't** work.

WinXP -> Host **works**.
WinXP -> Win98 **works**.
WinXP -> Win2012 **doesn't** work.

Win2012 -> Host **works**.
Win2012 -> Win98 **works**.
Win2012 -> WinXP **doesn't** work.

I have no idea why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XP and 2012 by default have a firewall enabled on interfaces... that blocks ICMP.  Have you made sure the windows firewall is disabled and/or allows ICMP?